# DSolve huge output

Tags: differential-equations

I get the correct answer for this differential equation

```
DSolve[{
  D[Y[y], {y, 4}] - 2 p^2 Y''[y] + p^4 Y[y] == Const,
  Y[0] == 0, Y[b] == 0, Y'[0] == 0, Y'[b] == 0
  }
 , Y[y], y]
```

But if I replace `Const` with `Fn[1]` for example the output becomes too huge.

```
Fn[q_] := 2/(d*a) Integrate[q*Sin[p x], {x, 0, a}];d=18315;p=Pi n/a;
```

[image]
Why is that?

Comment: Try `Const` with `(173797/5000000000 (a - a Cos[n Pi]))/(a n)`.`DSolve` is symbolic solver and likes exact values.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk it works, but in future I want to replace `Const` with a result of function Fn[q_]

Comment: Your *code* does not reproduce the image. I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/LrLqL.png.

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry I forgot to add `p=Pi n/a` in question

Comment: @MichaelE2 and I don't know why, but I have `Fn[1]=(0.0000347594 (1 - Cos[n Pi]))/n`, not  `2/18315*...`